# Spring Boot Project with multiple developers with restrictions

Tags: spring-boot

I want to create spring boot app with multiple developers but i don't have certain developer to see some part of the project like application.properties
Can someone guide me please

Comment: Please provide more info, such as the IDE used

Comment: I need help from you if you can provide IDE with the solution